# In symfony 2 how to access twig templating base url parameter in php?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How do I access base url in service or any other class ?

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        packages:
            assets:
                base_urls: ["http://assets.acme.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally:

```
$assetUrl = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path, $packageName);
```

In your case:

```
$baseUrl = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('', 'assets');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code is in `app/config/config/yml`

Look, this code is in my controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
[...]

$configfile = Yaml::parse($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/config/config.yml');
baseurls = $configfile['framework']['templating']['packages']['assets']['base_urls']);
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to mention base_url into parameter section 
like

parameters:
      base_urls: http://assets.acme.com

and then with the help of **container** object you can access into any services or class.

like in Controllar use

$this->container->getParameter('base_urls');

Comment: The question is about accessing parameters under templating >> assets.